# Linear regression and randomized controlled trials

Tags: regression, linear

I wonder whether linear regression analysis is a right statistical tool for randomized controlled trials. For example, finding the determinants of endline measurement of ferritin (dependent variable) and one of the determinants is baseline ferritin. Does this make sense? I mean there is a supplementation as well involved.

Comment: Clarify at least that ferritin is a protein and define what you mean by endline measurement because if you wish to be helped you have to take into account that people here are not doctors

Comment: @user256811 Define determinant for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Controlling for the baseline value of your outcome variable (ferritin) is quite standard and you would do this with a linear regression which also included the (presumably binary) categorical variable for treatment. You could also introduce other predictors which theory suggests might be accounting for variation in ferritin. The object of all this is to remove individual variation in your outcome to provide a more precise estimate of the intervention.

People do also introduce as predictor variables which have empirically proved to be unbalanced between the groups despite randomisation as a precaution against falsely claiming the treatment affected the outcome when it was really selection bias.